# Modifying Page content in a Storage Extension

Tags: content-delivery, deployer, storage-extensions

Is it possible to modify Page content in a Storage Extension before the Page is saved to the file system/broker DB ?

**Solution (provided by Atila):**

```
CharacterDataString newPageContent = new CharacterDataString(page.getPublicationId(),page.getId(),"New page content");
super.create(newPageContent, relativePath);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is. This is exactly what SI4T does. Speaking of which, it is open source so feel free to take a look at how exactly does it accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the "output" in a storage extension, but is important that you understand where/when to do so. If/When possible, I'd recommend exploring the possibility to do so in a TBB which requires less (or none) deployment/infrastructure/configuration work.

If you could elaborate more on what is it that you are trying to accomplish and why, I'll be happy to shed some thoughts. If you still think a storage extension is the way to go, look at the `PageDeploy` module/step (depending on the version of deployer you are extending)